# How to monitor Datastore v1beta3 API? What are the quota limits?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I'm moving from v1beta2 to v1beta3 using ruby gcloud gem. I have some questions which are not clear from documentation.

What API I supposed to enable to use it? Is it "Google Cloud Datastore API" ? For v1beta2 it was "Google Cloud Datastore API (v1beta2)". Reason I'm asking is that after migration my project is working, however if I go to "Google Cloud Datastore API" -> Usage, I see zero activity. I also don't see any activity in AppEngine which used to be with v1beta2.

Also in v1beta2 we had some quotas (100,000,000 requests/day; 50,000 requests/100seconds/user) visible on quotas pages. I can not find any information about v1beta3 quotas. Does it have any? Do you know if they are documented somewhere? There is 17000 Discovery requests per 100 seconds on that quota page, but what are the Discovery requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for access outside of App Engine use 'Google Cloud Datastore API'

For API usage and Quotas,at the moment you still need to look App Engine -> Quotas.